# Compare two sentences

Tags: xcode

I have a sentence and after that, some one edited this sentence. I would like to highlight changes in new sentence.
Is there any code or algorithm for this? Please help me.

Ex:

Org:     I are a student in national university.

Edited:  I am a teacher in high school

Highlight:    am    teacher  high  school

Comment: google for com.googlecode.java-diff-utils

Comment: So, you have a project in xcode, java and php?